# Writing a bash script that writes a variable to the end of a line in another file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to add a line to a bash script that does a bunch of other stuff and what I want it to do is write to the end of a line in another file.  I have a file with a line of IP addresses which is all one line.  This script that I have written asks for user input and one of those things it asks for is an IP address.  That gets stored as a variable inside_ip I want to write that to the end of a line in another file.  I found a similar question and the solution was

```
sed -i.bck '$s/$/yourText2/' list.txt
```

I tried to put that in a file with

`sed -i.bck '$s/$/ $inside_ip/' list.txt`

but it actually writes $inside_ip to the end of the file, so I just need it to print the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes stop variables from being expanded.  Double quotes allow them to be expanded.  Hence:

```
sed -i.bck '$s/$/ '"$inside_ip/" list.txt
```

That protects the `$s` in single quotes; you want `sed` to see the `$` and the `s`, not the value of your (probably unset) shell variable `$s`.  Of course, if the file only contains one line, then the leading `$` is not critical; you could leave it out, or replace it with `1`.  The `/$/` would be left alone anyway, but the double quotes following expand the variable, preserving any spaces inside it (though IP addresses don't usually contain spaces).

Comment: Thank you guys so much!  This one worked sed -i.bck '$s/$/ '"$inside_ip/" list.txt  I was trying brackets and every other thing.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following work for you?

```
echo $inside_ip >> list.txt
```

Comment: That would add the new IP on a new line at the end of the file (assuming there is a newline at the end of the file at the moment).  It would be better design for the file format to have each IP address on its own line (a lot easier to manage under Unix), but it isn't the format the OP claims to want.

Answer (score 2):

use `"`'s instead of `'`'s as in `sed -i.bck "s/$/ $inside_ip/" list.txt`